# useEffect with if statement not working React

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks

I'm trying to set a value to id 'packageStatus' when the value of package is an empty string..
The error in the console says:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children').
I've tried placing the if statement before and after getParent(), but it doesn't work.
This is my database where you can se package under children:

```
{
  "parents": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Anna",
      "adress": "Skatgatan 6",
      "children": [
        {
          "age": "2 månader",
          "package": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "packages": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "size": "Small strl: 44-50"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "size": "MEDIUM strl: 50-56"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "size": "Large strl: 56-62"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my React component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../style/Welcome.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import '../style/Button.css';

const Welcome = () => {
  const [parent, setParent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getParent = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/parents/0').then(
        (response) => response.json()
      );
      // update the state
      setParent(response);
    };
    getParent();
    //if() not working...
    // if (parent.children[0].package === "") {
    //     getParent();
    //     document.getElementById('packageStatus').innerHTML = 'inget klädpaket ännu';
    //   }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col bg-white h-full bg-opacity-80'>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='mt-8 space-y-8'>
        <div className='text-black text-4xl font-bold'>
          {parent && <h1>Välkommen {parent.name}!</h1>}
        </div>
        <div className='bg-white mx-8 shadow-lg py-4 rounded-lg'>
          {parent && (
            <div className='space-y-4 text-xl'>
              <div>
                <p>
                  Du har{' '}
                  <span className='font-bold'>{parent.children.length}</span>{' '}
                  barn registrerat
                </p>
                <p>
                  som är{' '}
                  <span className='font-bold'>{parent.children[0].age}</span>{' '}
                  gammalt.
                </p>
                <p>
                  och har{' '}
                  <span id='packageStatus' className='font-bold'>
                    {parent.children[0].package}
                  </span>
                  .
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>Din registrerade adress är:</p>
                <p>{parent.adress}</p>
              </div>
              <p className='text-orange-300 underline'>
                Stämmer inte dina uppgifter?
              </p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='mt-auto p-4'>
        <button className='bg-orange-400 text-2xl rounded-lg px-16 py-2'>
          <Link to='/Select'>GÅ VIDARE</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React's state updates aren't immediate](https://betterprogramming.pub/why-dont-react-state-updates-reflect-immediately-9041c4377385). Therefore, after calling `getParent`, parent is `null`. Only after the `fetch` request completes and React's state update complete, `parent` will not be `null` (if `response` is not `null`).

What you can do is set the `parent` in `useEffect` dependencies and first check if the `parent` is defined:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getParent = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/parents/0').then(
            (response) => response.json()
        );
        // update the state
        setParent(response);
    };
    getParent();

    if (parent && parent.children[0].package === "") {
        getParent();
        document.getElementById('packageStatus').innerHTML = 'inget klädpaket ännu';
    }
    // parent is in useEffect's dependency list
}, [parent]);
```

An even better solution would be to use a second `useEffect` and extract `getParent` function:

```
const getParent = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/parents/0').then(
        (response) => response.json()
    );
    // update the state
    setParent(response);
};

useEffect(() => {
    getParent();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (parent && parent.children[0].package === "") {
        getParent();
        document.getElementById('packageStatus').innerHTML = 'inget klädpaket ännu';
    }
}, [parent]);
```

Comment: Thank you! The first alternative worked perfectly. The second one gave me alot of errors. 'setParent' is not defined, and: Unexpected use of 'parent', all over the place. the warning says: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'parent'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'parent' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.
I mean the first one works- but out of quriosity-  do you know why this happens with the second option?

Comment: @KarinLundqvist are you sure that you included this line `const [parent, setParent] = useState(null);` in the second example? Here's a [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-jackson-tscflj?file=/src/App.js) representing the second example, which doesn't have any errors.

Comment: haha found the issue.. copy pasted away a letter.. Thank you again!